# Getting Error in Django API?

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-views, gunicorn

When using Nginx and Gunicorn server I am getting the following error when sending both `GET` and `POST` requests.

```
POST net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I got this error while sending a `POST` request to fetch a bunch of data, nearly 20000 records. The same request works when fetching a lesser amount of data.

It works fine in my default server, it's only while using Nginx and Gunicorn server I have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For my above issue. i checked CPU process using htop. while hitting particular API which is actually a big data collections my cpu process went 100% and RAM increasing so only it occurs. for that kill some not used process which occupy RAM. so you won't get EMPTY RESPONSE after that. but it is not a best solution. is their any thing have better than this means suggest thanks.